# Add observaleList items from Service file to another in controller file, but gives empty list

Tags: java, javafx

When I display the observaleList, it works but when I want to add their elements to another it doesn't work. It gives me an empty list.

**controller file**

```
ObservableList<String> ListE=FXCollections.observableArrayList();


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       ListE=le.getAllNomE(nc);
        for(String cl : ListE){
        choiceET.getItems().add(cl);}
                choiceET.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();




               AddButton.setOnAction(e->{
                   //System.out.println(choiceET.getValue());
                   if(cls.getText().isEmpty())
                   System.out.println("null");
                   else
                                          //System.out.println(cls.getText());
                                          System.out.println(nc);
                                        System.out.println(ListE);
                                        System.out.println(le.getAllNomE(nc));




    });

    }
```

**service file**

```
public ObservableList<String> getAllNomE(String NomClasse) {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String requete = "select nomE,prenomE from Etudiant where classe=(select idClasse from classe where nomClass=\""+NomClasse+"\")";
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        Statement st =con.createStatement();
        rs= st.executeQuery(requete);
        while(rs.next()){
            String nomPre=rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2);
            list.add(nomPre);
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServiceClasse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return list ;
}
```

**output**

```
3a11

[]

[Ridene Oussama, nom3 prenom3, test1 test1]
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. and stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: Will this help me to find the solution?

Comment: I'm not totally clear what frameworks/libraries you are using and what you expect your code to do. A MRE would let me run the code myself to investigate the unexpected behavior. Also -- any Java IDE should have an auto-format function that will correctly space out and indent your code so it's easy for people online to read.

Comment: Better title, fix typos, add code alignment